# Bluetooth and Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-10, audio, remote-desktop, bluetooth, microphone

I have an odd use case, and I am trying to find a way to make it work.

I have a windows desktop for my home computer, it is running windows 10.  I also have a windows 10 laptop provided by my employer.  In order to use my full size keyboard/mouse/monitor I typically connect to the laptop from my desktop using rdp.  This works fine, I have my laptop running in an RDP session on one desktop monitor and my other monitor is free for anything else. This works great and I have been very happy with it.

Where I am running into problems, is that we use ms teams internally for meetings and conference calls.  I am struggling to find a workable solution for audio for these meetings.

I have tried the following,

1. Configure RDP to send audio to the local computer (my desktop).  This works fine for audio playback, but I am not able to send audio input from my local computer(desktop) to the remote computer(laptop).
2. I tried using a bluetooth headset connected to the laptop.  I get some audio (system sounds).  The headset is recognized as a device my teams, but no audio is sent or received from the headset.
3. I tried plugging a logitech headset directly into the laptop, and windows seems to recognize the headset fully.  When I look at the sound settings I see the "test your microphone" bar moving around, system sounds are played through the headset as well.  I don't get any application audio sent to the headphones and microphone input isn't picked up by teams, or other applications.

I realize this is a little bit odd, and RDP isn't often used to connect to a device sitting right next to you, but I feel like this should be possible somehow, but I am missing it

Answer (score 2):

I realized I never came back to this.  In the end rebooting both systems resolved the issue.  Audio pass through worked in both directions using a headset connected to my desktop.  Should have tried a reboot before much earlier in the troubleshooting process.